# Strange compiling error of visual studio .sln on remote agent

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, bamboo

In bamboo plan I use Visual studio task,

[image]

And I got strange semantic errors:

> ListingPages\DiamondListingPage.cs(52,69): 
>   error CS1519:  Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>   TestBase.cs(64,44): error CS1056:  Unexpected character '$'
>   JewelryListingPage.cs(38,44): error CS1519:  Invalid token '=' in
>   class, struct, or interface member declaration

But in local Visual studio everything is ok!

So how to reproduce those errors in local VS or how to fix it on remote bamboo agent?

Comment: Can you show the line(s) of code in question?  Are the c# versions the same in both environments?  My crystal ball guess:  You're using c# 6 locally which support string interpolation using the $ symbol but your remote environment doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

So, I change the project support language to C# in my local VS, and after it found all problem places by using ReSharper.